# PBKDF2 PRF: HMAC or just hash?

Tags: pseudo-random-function, pbkdf-2

I understand the way $\textrm{PBKDF2}$ can be used to 'stretch' a password/passphrase that does not provide full entropy.

My question: how does one choose the PRF? A common choice is any well-known cryptographic hash like $\textrm{SHA256}$, and I understand why that works. Some systems, however, use $\textrm{HMAC}_{\textrm{SHA256}}$, where the password is used to key the MAC.

Why would one use $\textrm{HMAC}_{\textrm{SHA256}}$ over $\textrm{SHA256}$ as the PRF? I don't see any advantage to this. Surely the weaknesses of Merkle-Dåmgard hashes adressed by $\textrm{HMAC}$ are irrelevant when the password is a secret used to derive another secret?

Comment: A PRF has two inputs, a key and a message. A hash has only one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HMAC is sometimes called a *keyed* hash. The key is not part of the input of a secure hash (as CodesInChaos already indicated in the comments). HMAC is a relatively simple construct to allow a key to be used as input to the underlying secure hash. It specifically is constructed to disallow length extension attacks - although those are not likely an issue in PBKDF2.

You could use If you'd use SHA-256 directly you would have to make sure you're not vulnerable against those kind of attacks. You would basically be without the security proofs of HMAC.

KDF1 and KDF2 are KDFs/PRFs that simply concatenate elements in a certain way before entering the result into the hash. SHA-3/KMAC will (largely) be a concatenation of key and message before hashing. So it certainly can be done that way.

---

You should however reverse your question: *Why **wouldn't** you use a secure PRF instead of directly using a hash?*.

HMAC is relatively efficient. Inn PBKDF2 (which requires a work factor / iteration count) the small inefficiencies may actually be a benefit (a good implementation should however store the intermediate hash value of the password, otherwise an attacker may have an advantage).

Furthermore, HMAC is still considered secure, even if the underlying hash is vulnerable to certain kind of attacks (such as those against MD5 and SHA-1).

For the SHA-1 and SHA-2 algorithms I'd advice you to keep to HMAC unless you've got very strong (performance related?) reasons not to.

Comment: I'm still thinking of a way to explain that both KBKDF's and MAC algorithms are PRF's.

Comment: Funfact: Many of the recent hash functions (BLAKE, BLAKE2, Skein, ...) have built-in MAC modes which _could_ be a replacement for the full HMAC construction here.

Comment: I understand how both KBKDFs and MACs are PRFs, that was what my question was about. I couldn't see why HMAC's protection against e.g. length extension attacks was needed; but as you said: one would use HMAC just to be safe. That answers my question.

Comment: @SEJPM Yeah, I just kept to the one that (I hope) becomes standardized in the answer. I could have included a lot of other MAC and KDF constructions as well. Feel free to post them as fun-facts :)

Comment: DiscobarMolokai: I presumed you understood about them from your question, but answers should be written with a large audience in mind. Welcome to crypto, by the way!

Comment: Do you have a good example of how length extension attacks or collision attacks might be turned into PBKDF2 exploits? I presume certain rainbow table computations might be slightly easier, but perhaps you have a really good example?

Comment: A naive implementation of HMAC costs four compression instead of two. This results in a factor 2 weakening for PBKDF2 if you use such an implementation (e.g. the .NET one).

Comment: @HenrickHellström No, not for PBKDF2. The length extension attacks are mainly an issue for direct use as MAC.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I've added the weakening part within the answer. I presume it is correct this way (note that I've left out ipad & opad for convenience). Please comment if it is not.